# Handle Nan when using Pandas ExcelWriter in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan, xlsxwriter, spreadsheet-excel-writer

How would I change the following code to handle NaN values as just empty cells within my dataframe as I iterate through it line by line outputting values in column A?

```
excel = pd.ExcelWriter(f_name,engine='xlsxwriter')
wb = excel.book
ws = wb.add_worksheet('PnL')

for i in len(df):
  ws.write(0,i,df.iloc[i]['A'])
```

Comment: Maybe try `df = df.fillna('')`

Comment: I would like to preserve the values in df if possible

Comment: also to add... it did not work

Comment: i could do `0 if np.isnan(df.iloc[i]['A']) else df.iloc[i]['A'`  but that is really comber-sum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

or:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(0)
```

But better is use [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45, np.nan], 
                   'B': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45, np.nan]})
print df
    A   B
0  10  10
1  20  20
2  30  30
3  20  20
4  15  15
5  30  30
6  45  45
7 NaN NaN

#create subset, because cannot write Series to excel
df1 = df[['A']]

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('f_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object, instead NaN give 0
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PnL', na_rep=0)

# Save content
writer.save()
```

If you want omit index and header, add parameters `index=False` and `header=False`:

```
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PnL', na_rep=0, index=False, header=False)
```

[image: excel]

Comment: Could it be that `writer.save()` is missing?

Comment: @ikku100 - I think if use `df.to_excel` not necessary like here.

Comment: It didn't work for me until I did. But perhaps when the writer is destroyed it saves it, which happens when you run a .py from start to finish and the kernel ends. When running in jupyter notebooks, not so much.

Comment: @ikku100 - You are right, missing `writer.save()`, added to answer.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend copying the dataframe, changing the NANs to spaces and then writing the data. Your original dataframe will still have the NANs.

Also, as a workaround Xlsxwriter supports writing writing NANs mapped to formulas that yield an error code. However, this is a constructor option and isn't on by default. See the [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html?highlight=nan#constructor).

If you have a version of Pandas >= 0.16 you should be able to turn on the option as follows:

```
excel = pd.ExcelWriter(f_name,
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True})
```

Comment: If there is some nan value in the data you got this error: TypeError: NAN/INF not supported in write_number() without 'nan_inf_to_errors' Workbook() option. I use options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True}, and works pretty fine.

Comment: Hi, how do I make it map nans to a #N/A value?